# Error when executing osrm-extract on a pbf file

Tags: openstreetmap, osrm

I am installing an OpenStreetmap Server with osrm-backend and I have this error when executing the `osrm-extract` command.

The linux command result :

```
root@osrm:~/osrm-backend/build# ./osrm-extract -p profile.lua champagne.osm.pbf
[info] Using script profile.lua
[info] Input file: champagne.osm.pbf
[info] Profile: profile.lua
[info] Threads: 1
[STXXL-MSG] STXXL v1.4.0 (prerelease/Debug)
[STXXL-ERRMSG] Warning: no config file found.
[STXXL-ERRMSG] Using default disk configuration.
[STXXL-MSG] Disk '/var/tmp/stxxl' is allocated, space: 1000 MiB, I/O implementation: syscall autogrow delete_on_exit queue=0
[info] Parsing in progress..
[info] input file generated by Osmium (http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osmium)
[info] timestamp: 2016-10-29T19:28:02Z
[info] Found 3 turn restriction tags:
[info]   motorcar
[info]   motor_vehicle
[info]   vehicle
[info] Parsing finished after 1381.82 seconds
[info] Raw input contains 6140969 nodes, 843282 ways, and 13341 relations
[extractor] Sorting used nodes        ... ok, after 1.46194s
[extractor] Erasing duplicate nodes   ... ok, after 0.838968s
[extractor] Sorting all nodes         ... ok, after 24.7631s
[extractor] Building node id map      ... ok, after 11.7569s
[extractor] setting number of nodes   ... ok
[extractor] Confirming/Writing used nodes     ... ok, after 5.89633s
[info] Processed 691873 nodes
[extractor] Sorting edges by start    ... ok, after 8.12096s
[extractor] Setting start coords      ... ok, after 10.5156s
[extractor] Sorting edges by target   ... ok, after 11.2438s
[extractor] Computing edge weights    ... ok, after 14.5457s
[extractor] Sorting edges by renumbered start ... ok, after 12.5273s
[extractor] Writing used edges       ... ok, after 0.953764s
[extractor] setting number of edges   ... ok
[info] Processed 726848 edges
[extractor] Sorting used ways         ... ok, after 0.936119s
[extractor] Sorting 216 restriction. by from... ok, after 0.165142s
[extractor] Fixing restriction starts ... ok, after 0.116496s
[extractor] Sorting restrictions. by to  ... ok, after 0.205293s
[extractor] Fixing restriction ends   ... ok, after 0.499374s
[info] usable restrictions: 203
[extractor] writing street name index ... ok, after 0.756388s
[info] extraction finished after 1518.52s
[info] Generating edge-expanded graph representation
[info]  - 203 restrictions.
[info] Importing n = 691873 nodes 
[info]  - 154 bollard nodes, 969 traffic lights
[info]  and 726848 edges 
[info] Graph loaded ok and has 726848 edges. 10% . 20% . 30% . 40% . 50% . 60% . 70% . 80% . 90% . 100%
[info] Node compression ratio: 0.171614
[info] Edge compression ratio: 0.21115. 10% . 20% . 30% . 40% . 50% . 60% . 70% . 80% . 90% . 100%
[info] Generated 726549 nodes in edge-expanded graph
[info] generating edge-expanded edges. 10% . 20% . 30% . 40% . 50%         
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'boost::numeric::positive_overflow'
what():  bad numeric conversion: positive overflow
Abandon
```

Can someone tell me how to resolve it please?

I am using Debian 8.6 (Jessie)

Comment: Please post text, not screenshots of text. This makes it hard for others to search for the error message or to find your question.

Comment: I post it in a response.
Thanks

Comment: Which exact OSRM version are you using? According to https://github.com/Project-OSRM/osrm-backend/issues/2243 this has been a bug in the 5.0(.0?) release or pre-release.

Comment: How i can find the version?

Comment: I use the version that i have cloned in the past week